# Vuejs: Insert date today in input

Tags: date, vue.js, input

I am using an input for the date. How do we set the Input to display the Date Today? Thank you for your time.

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Debarred</label>
                                <input v-model="form.debarred" type="date" name="debarred"
                                       placeholder="Debarred"
                                       class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('debarred') }">
                                <has-error :form="form" field="debarred"></has-error>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the model value `form.debarred` on page load like:

```
this.form.debarred = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
//==> "2020-04-03"
```

Now, using `.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')` is need here as [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) value can only accept a string representing a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, or empty.

DEMO:

```js
const debarred = document.querySelector('[name=debarred]');
debarred.value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Debarred</label>
  <input type="date" name="debarred" placeholder="Debarred" class="form-control">
  <has-error :form="form" field="debarred"></has-error>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you!

I'm using vue.js and I placed your code in the script `this.form.debarred = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');` it worked like charm.

Comment: Do you have a patreon? How can I remove the time for this code ```                console.log(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toLocaleString('en-CA'));```

Comment: Sorry, but I will be be offline soon. Can't help at the moment. Please post a new question regarding it. I am sure someone will be glad to help. Also, post the question link here. I will try to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try this: `new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toLocaleString('en-CA').split(',')[0]`